# How to make a demo video using a Mac?

Tags: mac, video

How can a simple demonstration video like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DElYOhids8Y) be made using a Mac?

In particular, I need:

1. To edit and cut some of the raw materials, as some of it may not be very interesting to the audience.
2. Add some words in the video.

Could anyone can give me some help?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this:

1. Preparing your content: screenshot the pages you want to present. Use `Cmd+Shift+4` to get all the screens. Don't worry about getting some incorrectly, just do a few tries is you have to, you can filter them out later.
2. Build a presentation: create slides, add highlights and transition animations,  time it just right and practice your speech. You can use Apple Keynote for this, or any other presentation software.
3. Record your show: do your screencast in "Present" mode and record your screen. Open QuickTime player and use the option File → New Screen Recording to get some (limited) editing options after you record it. On the start screen, set the audio recording options to pick up or ignore your microphone

If you want to fine-tune the result, or to export it to other formats, make an iMovie project out of it.

Enjoy :-)

Answer (score -1):

The beginning of the video shows the paper title. A simple Google search would lead you to http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=7203040, which is the paper describing the tool.

It is usual in papers describing software to offer a download link in the paper, so I would suggest buying the paper. If there isn't a link inside, or it's not OSX compatible, you could then write your own version based on the description in the paper.

Edit:
misinterpreted the question. To record the screen, you can use quicktime then a video editor to add annotations etc.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but what I am asking is *how to make the demo video like they did*. Are there any tools on MAC can do this? I think `quicktime` might not provide sufficient functionality.

Comment: Misinterpreted the question. To record the screen, you can use quicktime then a video editor to add annotations etc.